# Azure Pipelines: How does the pipeline know a step failed?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'm just getting into Azure Pipelines, so I expect this is a fairly simple question.  How does the pipeline know if a step failed?

Background, I am writing a validation program that needs to let the pipeline know if the whole pipeline should fail or succeed.  What does the script need to do to let the pipeline know that the task has failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Pipelines has a couple of ways to tell if a step failed:

- `Exit code <> 0` - When a script executes it can set an exit code. Azure Pipelines can check the exit code and fail the step when the exit code isn't 0.
- `echo "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]"` - [There are "magic strings" a task can log to the console to tell the agent something went wrong](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#complete-finish-timeline).
- `stdErr` - Messages from a task can be sent to the "output" or "error" stream. An Azure Pipelines task can be configured to fail when data is written to the Error stream.
- `crash` - When the executable crashes and unexpectedly terminates, the task will be marked as failed.
- Timeout - Some steps track the time taken and will kill the step if a timeout occurs.
- REST API - The final option for a task is to use some of the undocumented REST API to set the status of, or cancel, the job.

Not all of these options are available everywhere and not every task is configured to act on all 6 of these options. But in general these are the ways a step can signal failure to the agent.

When you're using the `script:`, `pwsh:`, `bash:` or `powershell:` steps, you can configure the behavior you want:

```
steps:
- bash: 
  failOnStderr: true
  continueOnError: false
  timeoutInMinutes: 5
```

Returning a non-0 exit code will also fail a script step.

Custom tasks can use the VstsTaskSdk or the Azure-Pipelines-Task-Lib to communicate with the agent. Under the hood this uses the same exit code, fail on stdErr and `##vso` command strings methods to signal success or failure.

Answer (score 1):

Usually always on Windows/Linux the exitcode of the executed process will be checked. In the case of a build-step for example you execute something like `dotnet build ...`. If the exitcode of the process is 0 then the build was successful. If the exitcode is a non-zero-number then the build was not successful. In general nearly all programs have this exitcode-behavior.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way is to check the result under pipeline UI.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks but how does the pipeline know the 'Build solution **\*.sln' failed?